# Sub menu bar not visible

Tags: wordpress, css

The **sub menu** bar of this site is not visible i am using constellation theme of wordpress 
i have tried using changing margins but not able to figure it out it is responsive

no i am talking about child of the menu bar  actually if u can see the code about page has 2 child submenu which should be visible as a dropdown but it is not visible

Comment: are you talking about sidebar?

Comment: no i am talking about submenu or dropdown menu of menubar

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell looking at what you have provided so far. But If I see your page I see this script as 404, [LINK](http://trichometechnology.com/wp-content/themes/constellationjs/script.js?ver=3.4.1)

Is this js showing.hiding your menu. Also I see one section of navigation as commented out.  But if you could fix those 2 404's , it would give a better Idea as to what is happening. I guess nav show/hide is being driven by the script that is actually not there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually other site is also using the same theme as it is jasilaw.com here the dropdown is working fine if it is js scrip issue then it should also have the same problem